# Change dictionary to string value in aggregate function MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b04e99a27287e071fb50093"),
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Lucy"
    }
}
```

I want to get customer name like this

```
{
    "custumer_name" : "lucy"
}
```

How to do that ?

Comment: I would advise that you don't. It's actually a far simpler process to do such transforms "after" you receive data from the database. Unless you are "significantly" reducing the payload of what gets returned in response, then the overhead involved in the server processing that transformation is usually not worth the cost compared to doing it once the request is received. The code is far less terse in your programming language ( python? You mentioned dictionary ) of choice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in a few ways.

You can use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregation pipeline stage. And the [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) aggregation pipeline operator for the string transformation to lowercase.

`$addFields` example:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "custumer_name": { $toLower: "$customer.name" }
    }
}
```

`$project` example:

```
{
    $project: {
        "custumer_name": { $toLower: "$customer.name" },
        [ ... other elements ...]
    }
}
```

If you don't need the the string transformation to lowercase, then just use `"$customer.name"` instead of `{ $toLower: "$customer.name" }`.

The best solution depends on the details of your final needs.